# OpenOffice3 with 32bit JRE in CentOS6 64bit

Tags: centos, openoffice, jre

I want to know if it is possible and how to install headless Open Office 3 with 32 bit JRE on CentOS6 64 bit.

I need to set it in $HOME directory on Webfaction hosting.

Open Office they already have is 64 bit, and consumes 20 mb more ram than it used to on the previous 32 bit machine.

It also have to work with python via pyuno.

This is output from `java -version`:

```
java version "1.6.0_17"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.9) (rhel-1.36.b17.el6_0-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Which JRE are you using? Open or Sun?

Comment: I think they have OpenJDK.